# Sound settings not working

Tags: sound, system-settings

I once installed PulseAudio Equalizer but since it didn't work properly I did not want to use it. The annoying thing is that sound went through it by default so I had to go to the sound settings and change output every time I booted. Uninstalling the equalizer or disable it didn't change this. I tried to change the default output by editing `/etc/asound.conf`. Since it didn't exist I created it, but it had no effect. I tried to clean up after myself by removing the file but then things got out of hand. The sound disappeared and the sound settings now looks like this

[image: sound settings]

By running `sudo alsa force-reload`, I can get the sound back, but the sound settings remains broken. I have looked at questions similar to mine, but they provide no solution to my problem(s).

Some answers provided to these questions says that the questioner should run:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

When I run this I get:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all I had to do was to remove PulseAudio Equalizer.